# How to enable underscore (shortcut mnemonics) for menu items?

Tags: windows-vista, keyboard-shortcuts, context-menu, mnemonics

Is there a way to enable shortcut keystrokes from Windows Vista by default?

E.g. the following context menu item doesn't display a shortcut key:

[image]

Comment: Great question.. The mnemonic keys still work, but there's no telling what they are without guessing.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to open the Ease of Access Center.
2. There click on *Make the keyboard easier to use*.

   [image: Illustration for "Make the keyboard easier to use"]
3. Then tick the checkbox *Underline keyboard shortcuts and access keys*.

   [image: Illustration for "Underline keyboard shortcuts and access keys"]

It seems that they are displayed by default if you open the context menu with the keyboard either by pressing the appropriate key or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks, Johannes Rossel.  That's exactly what I was looking for.  Access keys..

Comment: @Gareth, everything under /dump on my server will remain there indefinitely as well, so no need to overzealously edit all of my posts.

Comment: Works for Windows 8 too.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 10 Users:

1. Win + U  or Settings => Ease of Access to open **[Ease of Access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2i2u.png)**
2. Select Keyboard Options
3. Under Other Settings, Turn On **[Enable shortcut underlines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Bps3.png)**

Comment: Question was specifically for Windows Vista

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it is done on my XP box.

1. Control Panel --> Display --> Appearance
   or: control color  (from the Run dialog)
2. Effects
3. Un-check the item: 
   ☐ Hide underlined letters for keyboard navigation until I press the Alt key